# How can I convert if to switch?

Tags: c++, refactoring

Is there a way to convert C++ `if`s to `switch`es? Both nested or non-nested `if`s:

```
 if ( a == 1 ) { b = 1; } /*else*/
 if ( a == 2 ) { b = 7; } /*else*/
 if ( a == 3 ) { b = 3; }
```

It should, of course, detect if the conversion is valid or not.

This isn't a micro-optimization, it's for clarity purposes.

Comment: Text editors can do it ;)

Comment: Is this micro-optimization?  Compilers should create a jump table for these.

Comment: I don't know of any such tool. The easiest way will probably be a search/replace using your editor of choice.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's for code clarity.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm afraid this is a very special and narrowed use case of code refactoring features for any advanced IDE. Doubt that there's something covering that ...

Comment: NB in the example you give, the transformation is invalid (or not useful, depending on what exactly you do).

Comment: There are sure a lot of downvoters, for a question that seems about programming and has mostly prettystraightforwards answers: Yes or No, and why.  (I happen to think the No answer is wrong, if you're a pragmatist).

Answer (score 5):

In general, you ought to be able to do this with a [program transformation tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) that can process C++.

In specific, our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit can to do this, using source-to-source rewrites.  I think these are close to doing the job:

```
  default domain Cpp;
  rule fold_if_to_switch_initial(s: stmt_sequence, e: expression,
                                 k1: integer_literal, k2: integer_literal,
                                 a1: block, a2: block):
                       stmt_sequence->stmt_sequence
        = "\s
           if (\e==\k1) \a1 
           if (\e==\k2) \a2 "
        -> "\s
            switch (\e) {
                case \k1: \a1
                     break;
                case \k2: \a2
                     break;
            }" if no_side_effects(e) /\ no_impact_on(a1,e);

   rule fold_if_to_switch_expand(s: stmt_sequence, e: expression, c: casebody,
                                 k: integer_literal, a:action)
                       stmt_sequence->stmt_sequence
        = "\s
           switch (\e) { \c } 
           if (\e==\k) \a "
        -> "\s
            switch (\e) {
                \c
                case \k: \a
                     break;
            }" if no_side_effects(e) /\ no_impact_on(c,e);
```

One has to handle the cases where the if controls a statement rather than a block, cheesily accomplished by this:

```
      rule blockize_if_statements:(e: expression, s: statement):
            statement->statement
      =  "if (\e) \s" ->  "if (\e) { \s } ";
```

DMS works by using a full language parser (yes, it really has a full C++ parser option with preprocessor)
to process the source code and  the rewrite rules.   It isn't fooled by whitespace or comments, because it is operating on the parse trees. The text inside "..." is C++ text
(that's what the 'default domain Cpp' declaration says) with pattern variables \x; text outside the "..." is DMS's rule meta syntax, not C++.  Patterns match the trees and bind pattern variables to subtrees; rule right hand sides are instantiated use pattern variable bindings.  After applying the transformations,
it regenerates the (revised) source code from the revised trees.

OP insists, "It should, of course, detect if the conversion is valid or not.".  This is the point of the conditions at the end of the rules, e.g., 'if no_side_effect ... no_impact', which are intended to check that evaluating the expression doesn't change something, and that the actions don't affect the value of the expression.

Implementing these semantic checks is difficult, as one must take into account C++;s incredibly complex semantics.  A tool doing this must know at least as much as the compiler (e.g., names, types, properties of declarations, reads and writes), and then has to be able to reason about the consequences.   DMS at present is able to implement only some of these (we are working on full control and data flow analysis for C++11 now).  I would not expect other refactoring tools to do this part well, either, because of the complex semantics; I think it unlikely that situation will improve because of the effort it takes to reason about C++.

In OP's case (and this occurs fairly often when using a tool like DMS), one can assert that in fact these semantic predicates don't get violated (then you can replace them with "true" and thus avoid implementing them) or that you only care about special cases (e.g., the action is an assignment to a variable other than on in the expression), at which point the check becomes much simpler, or you can simulate the check by narrowing the acceptable syntax:

```
rule fold_if_to_switch_expand(s: stmt_sequence, v: identifier, c: casebody,
                                 k: integer_literal, v2: identifier, k2: integer_literal)
                       stmt_sequence->stmt_sequence
        = "\s
           switch (\v) { \c } 
           if (\v==\k) \v2=\k2; "
        -> "\s
            switch (\v) {
                \c
                case \k: \v2=\k2;
                     break;
            }" if no_side_effects(c);
```

Having said all this, if OP has only a few hundred known places that need this improvement, he'll probably get it done faster by biting the bullet and using his editor.   If he doesn't know the locations, and/or there are many more instances, DMS would get the job done faster and likely with many fewer mistakes.

(We've done essentially this same refactoring for IBM Enterprise COBOL using DMS,
without the deep semantic checks).

There are other program transformation tools with the right kind of machinery (pattern matching, rewriting) that can do this in theory.  None of them to my knowledge make any effective attempt to handle C++.

Comment: What if there will be a `#define` in a header at compile time but isn't there now? It seems that this transformation is only valid at compile time, but the OP asked for one that could be done prior to compiling, and quite likely with intervening source code changes.

Comment: @David Schwartz: By your argument, there are no source code changes that any agent, mechanical or human can make that are trustworthy, because some other agent can change some piece of code on which it depends.  True; so what? The software engineering profession thrives in spite of this, mostly by avoiding changes that have that kind of ripple effect.

Comment: Of course no source code changes are absolutely trustworthy. So that my argument leads to that conclusion is not a flaw in it. As you say, the solution is to avoid changes that have this kind of ripple effect. This kind of change, as I've argued, has this kind of ripple effect. It's the kind the profession thrives by avoiding.

Comment: You're arguing that "Changing a sequence of ifs (of this style) into a case statement" has this kind of ripple effect?  We refactor code all the time, assuming that the ripple effect of such refactoring is nil, or they wouldn't be refactorings.  I think I'm with OP on this one.

Comment: Read my answer. I showed how this kind of change has this kind of effect. Sure, this is the kind of change *humans* make all the time, but it's totally inappropriate for an automated change. (Except in the case where you can tell it has no semantic changes other than perhaps silly things like `#define case`. But in the OP's case, where the existing code could hit multiple cases but the refactored code can't, it's totally inappropriate for automation.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I did read your answer. You said, "definitions prior to your code may affect its semantics" (and I agree).  I said, "the tool needs to check about the impact of the changes" (side effects, etc.).  I also said, "you can simplify these checks in practice by making assumptions".  We've been over the consequences of changes elsewhere in the code.  Now, OP as an engineer has to decide what assumptions he is willing to make.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a text editor.

Step 1:
put MARK before your block of code, with possible leading tabs
Step 2:
Put END at the end of your block of code, with possible leading tabs
Step 3:
Load your file in vi of some kind.  Run something like this:

```
/^^T*MARK/
:.,/^^T*ENDMARK/ s/^\(^T*\)if/\1IIFF/g
:%s/IIFF *([^)]*) *{ *\([^}]*\)};? *$/TEST{\1}TSET {\2} break;/
:%s/TEST{\([^=}]*\)==\([^}]*\)}TSET/COND{\1}case \2:/g
?^^T*MARK?
/COND{/
:. s/COND{\([^}]*\)}/switch(\1) {^M^T/
:%s/COND{\([^}]*\)}/^T/g
:%s/^\(^T*\)ENDMARK/\1} \/\/switch/g
:%s/^^TMARK//g
```

where ^T is tab and ^M is a return character (which you may not be able to type directly, depending on what version of vi/vim you are using)

Code is written off the top of my head, and not tested.  But I've done things like this before.  Also, files containing `TEST{whatever}TSET` and `COND{whatever}` and `MARK` and `ENDMARK` and `IIFF` type constructs will be horribly mangled.

This does not check validity, it just converts things in exactly your format into a switch statement.

Limited validity checking could be done with some fancy-ass (for vi) making sure that the left hand side of the equality expression is the same for all lines.  It also doesn't handle else, but that is easily rectified.

Then, before checking in, you do a visual sweep of the modified code using a good comparison tool.